# How can i send click inputs at specific windows like inside chrome or games using Python?

Tags: python

Hello I want to make some bot like a Pixel Bots but i try a lots of things like win32 clicks pyautogui, tk and other things but my code is not working at a specific game i choosed. How can i send leftClick input at a inside of game with python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui to click.

For example, the following code will click in the position x=100 and y=200 of your screen:
`pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200)`

Check the [pyautogui doc](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) for more details.

```
0,0       X increases -->
+---------------------------+
|                           | Y increases
|                           |     |
|   1920 x 1080 screen      |     |
|                           |     V
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+ 1919, 1079
```

You can also use

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200) 
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: I tried PyAutoGui. The clicks are not working at the game i am trying. When i use the pyautogui.click(x, y) the click is not working at game window but its working at other windows

Comment: Are you game in fullscreen mode or do you have multiple monitors? Maybe you could send a click to set the screen to focus and then after one second click again. If multiple monitors just put in the first screen

Comment: İ Have a 2 monitors and the game is on my first screen. Game is not at fullscreen its windowed 1366*768.